# How can "unvalidated redirects and forwards" be exploited?

Tags: url-redirection

The OWASP example for [Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards) says that:

> The application has a page called “redirect.jsp” which takes a single parameter named “url”. The attacker crafts a malicious URL that redirects users to a malicious site that performs phishing and installs malware.

How does an attacker crafts a malicious URL and forces it on the victim? If one goes to `foo.bar`, fills a form and submits it, how can one be redirected to amalicious site?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say there is a url called `www.example.com/redirect.jsp?url=www.example.com/login` that is used to redirect to the login page. I craft a link to `www.example.com/redirect.jsp?url=www.myphishingsite.com/login` which redirects to my phishing site. People look at the domain name and think its legit. It can also be used to DOS something and conceal your identity from the target.
There is no form involved.

Answer (score 1):

@joe is correct about the nature of the attack (+1) yet there's a little more to it.  Namely, whose issue it is and why the issue happens.

Using the same example, let us say that `example.com` uses a redirect script, say, `example.com/redirect.php` that receives the parameter `url` and then performs an HTTP 302 (or 301) to the URL that is contained in the `url` parameter.   Now, let us also say that `example.com` contains **user generated** content, including URL to which the users link.

When a user posts a URL on `example.com`, say, `http://mywebsite.com/myarticle/`, then `example.com` displays this URL as:

```
href="http://example.com/redirect.php?url=http://mywesite.com/myarticle"
```

But why does `example.com` display the URL in that way instead of the plain URL?  Because `redirect.php` collects statistics about the links the users click.

So, what is the problem?  The problem is that I can add a URL on some other website that also hosts *user content*, completely unrelated to `example.com`, say on `facebook.com` that reads:

```
http://example.com/redirect.php?url=http://myphishingwebsite.com/script.php
```

And the user will click that thinking that it is a link leading to `example.com`.

Browsers often shorten long URLs but leave the domain in full, and some forums even make a domain stand out of a link; all that to prevent phishing through links into dodgy websites.  But in the example above `example.com` has destroyed these safeguards and will allow any website to be redirected to, whilst the domain you see when hovering over the link is always `example.com`.

---

#### Solution

The above is a problem of `example.com` and this doiman therefore should be classified as unsafe to browse to even that it does not contain any malicious content.

Instead of using an unchecked redirect, `example.com` should either make a whitelist of domains to which `redirect.php` can be used, or make domains in the `url` parameter stand out (e.g. prepend the domain in a high contrast colour) before the link itself and require a proper `Referer:` header during the redirect (so redirects can only happen from `example.com` itself).  Preferably, it should preform both fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with theses redirects:

1) **Leak of origin**

Let's say that you wrote an (insecure) web server that at one point puts the username & password of a user in a URL (i.e. a GET request). A redirect would tell a malicious where a user came from, letting them extract their credentials from the URL.

2) **False sense of trust**

Users can get redirected to a phishing site without knowing. A cautious user could be using the legit site and suddenly be redirected to a malicious site without them knowing. This user would continue to use the site like normal, possibly having already checked the URL, etc. I don't know about you, but I don't check the URL every time I move around a website.